# Only make the current version selected in the Sitecore publish action

Tags: sitecore, publish

I have a requirement to allow users of the web site to publish only the latest version and see only the latest version in the content editor mode.

Is this possible by making some kind of setting in Sitecore config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) **Publish Latest version**: The content will be edited in master database by content editor. When an item is published then only latest content version will be copied from master database to web database. The Web database contains only the latest published version.

2.) **Only See latest version in Content Editor**: AFAIK, there is no such setting available in config files. Alternatively, you can write one schedule task which will run after specified interval (say after every 30 mins) and remove the old versions except the latest version. Removed version may be kept as serialized XML form. So that you can restore the deleted version to content tree if required.

Answer (score 0):

The Security field of an item is marked as [shared]. Meaning the value of the security field would be the same across language- and number versions.

Unfortunately, no settings in the web.config file could help you.